# Adding jpeg library to C++ Qt Creator Project in ubuntu?

Tags: wrapper, qt-creator, libjpeg

I want to create a wrapper class for existing jpeg library. I have created the project in Qt creator ? Can anyone tell me how to link libjpeg8 in Qt Creator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
LIBS += -L/usr/lib -ljpeg8
```

in your .pro file

Comment: thanks :)
its working simply like this.

LIBS += -L/usr/lib -ljpeg